# syntax error, unexpected '′' (T_STRING) PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I am getting the following error while running PHP a script:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '′' (T_STRING)
```

. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­app/­filters.php:72

```
    Route::any(‘check/purchase-code’, function() {if ($code = Input::get(‘code’)) {ini_set(‘user_agent’, ‘Mozilla/5.0′);$result = “”;if ($result = 1) {Session::put(‘valid-usage’,’1′);return Redirect::route(‘install-db-info’);}}return Redirect::to(‘/install’);});
Route::filter(‘user-auth’, function()
```

Comment: Stop using "formatted quotes", use a proper IDE and not word processing software, that's probably your issue

Comment: If you really have `‘` as single quote you should change it to `'`.

Comment: Micrososoft Word should not be the IDE of your choice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line (Be Sure about `'` and `"`)

```
Route::any(‘check/purchase-code’, function() {if ($code = Input::get(‘code’)) {ini_set(‘user_agent’, ‘Mozilla/5.0′);$result = “”;if ($result = 1) {Session::put(‘valid-usage’,’1′);return Redirect::route(‘install-db-info’);}}return Redirect::to(‘/install’);});
Route::filter(‘user-auth’, function()
```

to this

```
Route::any('check/purchase-code', function() {if ($code = Input::get('code')) {ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0');$result = "";if ($result = 1) {Session::put('valid-usage','1');return Redirect::route('install-db-info');}}return Redirect::to('/install');});
Route::filter('user-auth', function()
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all  `‘` chracters with `'` or `"`.

You probably copied the code from the internet and something got wrong in the copy process

Comment: For The Entire Coding ?

Comment: yes, for the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Valid string delimiters in PHP are quote `'` and double quote `"`. Backtick or apostrophe is NOT on the list.

See docs: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php